# Wipe iPhone data

Tags: iphone, ios, command-line, secure-erase

Is it possible to completely wipe out iPhone data using `dd` tool? Something like this?

```
sudo dd if=/dev/random of=/...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't normally access iPhone file system directly and wipe the data. If you'd like to wipe data from your iPhone, you can erase all data and settings by going to Settings app → General → Reset → Erase All Content and Settings.